# Bash Scripting : How to loop over X number of files, take input and write to a file in the same line

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

So I have a program written in C that takes in some parameters: calling it `allcell`
some sample parameters: `-m 1800 -n 9`
the files being analyzed: `cfdT100-0.trj, cfdT100-1.trj, cfdT100-2.trj, cfdT100-3.trj, ... cfdT100-19.trj`
file being fed: `template.file`
out file: `result.file`

```
 $ allcell -m 1800 -n 9 cfdT100-[0-19].trj < template.file > result.file
```

But when I `htop`, I see that only `cfdT100-0.trj`, `cfdT100-1.trj` and `cfdT100-9.trj` are being read. How do I make the shell read all the files from 0-19 ?

Additionally, when I write a script file to automate this, how should I enclose the line? Will this work:

```
"$($ allcell -m 1800 -n 9 cfdT100-[0-19].trj < template.file > result.file)"
```

Comment: Learn how character classes work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to change your glob expression to `cfdT100-{0..19}.trj` instead.

```
neech@nicolaw.uk:~ $ echo cfdT100-{0..19}.trj
cfdT100-0.trj cfdT100-1.trj cfdT100-2.trj cfdT100-3.trj cfdT100-4.trj cfdT100-5.trj cfdT100-6.trj cfdT100-7.trj cfdT100-8.trj cfdT100-9.trj cfdT100-10.trj cfdT100-11.trj cfdT100-12.trj cfdT100-13.trj cfdT100-14.trj cfdT100-15.trj cfdT100-16.trj cfdT100-17.trj cfdT100-18.trj cfdT100-19.trj
```

Your quoting on the scripted version looks acceptable. Just change the glob.

Comment: Thanks. Does this change if I'm on bash?
Also I use user input to check the end file (19 in the given example) - so if I have a variable for that `var`.
So `"$(echo cfdT100-{0..$var}.trj)"` ?

Comment: Yes, I believe you can use variables in your glob.

Comment: I guess this is specific to my case and the program that I used, but writing it here anyway: had to use `set -x` or `set -o xtrace` before the lines where I used variables to expand the variables.

Answer (score 0):

> use recursion function for infinite loop

```
a()
{
echo "apple"
a
}
a
```

This the will make a infinite loop