# Bash Scripting: use of wildcards to select 2 digit file name appends

Tags: bash, wildcard

I want to run a program which takes in data from a set of files named in series:
`cfdT210-0.trj cfdT210-1.trj cfdT210-2.trj cfdT210-3.trj .. cfdT210-99.trj`
can I use:
`program cfdT210-{,?}?.trj > out.file`

What are the other ways?
I'm familiar with `{0..99}` method in bash. Thanks to [Neech](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43654154/7026168)

Comment: What's wrong with the bash method?

Comment: `cfdT210-{0..99}.trj` is the way to go

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams it works, but want to explore other wildcards that might work.

Comment: @anubhava Thanks, are you familiar with other ways to do this using wildcards though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test with `ls your_pattern`. I think you were trying to find all files with 1 or 2 digits

```
ls cfdT210-{,?}?.trj
```

To limit this to digits, use

```
ls cfdT210-{,[0-9]}[0-9].trj
```

I would use `cfdT210-*.trj` when I was sure that there are no other files that match `cfdT210-*.trj` in your set of files or use the `{0..99}`.

Comment: can't do `*` as there are filenames with 3 digit tails too. But yeah, your answer solves it, I had an extra curly bracket before `.trj` in my [original question] (https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/43658264/2) !